# Image not display in my android Phone

Tags: android, html

I've a mobile version of website http://bluearrowsystems.com/m/. It doesn't display image in my android device but it's ok in my PC/Desktop. I checked stackoverflow answer that says change the image extension to jpeg but didn't work. Why ?

Comment: Are you using which android device ?

Comment: @Rstar Yes I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Animated GIFs are supported since Android Froyo (2.2).**

Earlier versions does not support animated GIFS out of the box. You can take a look at the [Android Issue 3422](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422&q=gif&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) for more details.

**Updated :**

i have tested in **Galaxy Tab 2** (android 4.1.2)

[image]

[image]

**Xperia U (Android 2.3.7)**

[image]
[image]

Comment: is it working on your device? Actually after successfully enter the site your can see the index.php page where a logo show on top. This logo is not showing in my device. pass:123456789.

Comment: Strange!! Why It's not working in my device !

Comment: @AlexMojum tested on Xperia U , 2.3.7 , wait i'm posting pics

Comment: I understand, In my Opera Browser it's not showing the image but in other browser it's show the jpeg/animated image.

Comment: So the problem is Opera Browser ?

Comment: @AlexMojum yes it can be thats why i'm trying to find does opera support or not

Comment: found something https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422